# overflow-y not showing full text

Tags: css

I have following settings:

```
 <div class="some-class"
     [ngStyle]="{'white-space' : (some-condition) ? 'nowrap' : 'normal',
      'overflow-y' : (some-condition) ? 'hidden' : 'scroll',
      'overflow-x' : 'hidden',
      'text-overflow' : (some-condition) ? 'ellipsis' : 'clip',
      'height' : (some-condition) ? '14px' : '46px'
      }">
  Huge text........................
</div>
```

So my objective is to make text scrollable only vertically.

It works, but only partially.

Horizontal scroll is not shown, as expected. But full text is not displayed in vertical scroll, and only a part of text is scrolled and rest of the text is not diaplyed at all.

Comment: where's your `HTML` ?

Comment: What css preprocessor are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. I am quite new to front-end development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the magical powers of DuckDuckGo, I have found the answer to this question. Next time, I would recommend that you also use the magical powers of DDG (or if you want Google). Disclaimer: I am not advertising for DDG or Google, I just recommend doing research before posting a question of StackOverflow.

---

### The ANSWER

```
<style>
    width: 10%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    word-wrap: break-word;
</style>
```

You would then replace `width: 10%` with however long you want it to be.

#### The BreakDown

`width: 10%;` - width of element inside its parent element 
`overflow-x: hidden;` - disables scrolling on x-axis of element 
`overflow-y: scroll;` - enables scrolling on y-axis of element 
`word-wrap: break-word;` - enables word-wrap to wrap text around end of line